# Templating with user defined classes as a parameter

Tags: c++, templating

I'm having a bit of trouble with templating and composition-style coding. I have an object being created inside the constructor of another with the *this parameter. Sorry, if I'm being unclear. The code is as below:

In the outer.h file:

```
class outer {
  public:
    outer(int w, int l);
    int getWidth();
    int getLength();
  private:
    inner<outer> test(*this);
    int width;
    int length;
};

outer::outer(int w, int l) {
  width = w;
  length = l;
}

int outer::getLength() {
  return length;
}
```

In the inner.h file

```
template<typename T>
class inner {
  public:
    inner(T &name);
  private:
    int top;
    int bot;
};

template<typename T>
inner<T>::inner(T &name) {
    top = name.getLength() /2;
    bot = -name.getLength() / 2;
}
```

I don't know if this is allowed as I can't find anything online that addresses this. The compiler is having problems with the *this statement in outer.h.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Make sure you're compiling with C++11 and that your compiler supports that feature.

Comment: @chris only with `=` or `{}`, not with `()`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Oh yeah, that's right. I use {} whenever I can anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using C++03, you must perform initial assignments in the constructor.

```
class outer {
  public:
    outer(int w, int l);
    int getWidth();
    int getLength();
  private:
    // Member variables are initialized in the order they are declared here.
    int width;
    int length;
    inner<outer> test;
};

outer::outer(int w, int l)
  : width(w)
  , length(l)
  , test(*this)
{
}
```

**Edit:**  Kerrek SB also observes that the order of your variables need to be changed.  They are initialized in the order you declare them in the class and `test` **needs** to be initialized last, so the other variables are initialized.

Comment: Thank for the response. I tried this and the compiler throws the error "no match for call to '(inner<outer>) (outer&)'". Any ideas on what that means?

Comment: In any event that'd be undefined behaviour, because the integers aren't initialized in time.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for the spot check.